# Jasmine spy returns empty mostRecentCall object

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, requirejs, jasmine

I'm currently writing a Google Chrome extension and testing it with Jasmine 1.3.0. The extension is a fairly simple dictionary extension that takes a word that the user double-clicks on to highlight, passes it to the background, and makes some dictionary calls to display in a pop-up. Right now I'm trying to test that the background does in fact receive  message passed from the content script using requireJS (http://requirejs.org/). My first test, that `addListener` was called, passes, but the subsequent tests fail. Here is background_spec.js:

```
describe("background message passing", function() {

  beforeEach(function() {
    chrome = {
      runtime : {
        onMessage : {
          addListener : function() {}
        }
      }
    }
    spyOn(chrome.runtime.onMessage, 'addListener').andCallThrough();
  });

  it("should add a listener", function() {
    runs(function() {
      require(['background']);
    });

    waits(100);

    runs(function() {
      expect(chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });  

  it("should call the listener with a function", function() { 
    runs(function() {
      require(['background']); 
    });

    waits(100);

    runs(function() {
      expect(chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
        jasmine.any(Function));
    });
  });

  it("should save the input", function() {
    runs(function() {
      require(['background']);
    });
    waits(100);

    runs(function() {
      var word;
      listener = chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener.mostRecentCall.args[0];
      expect(listener).toBeDefined();
/*
      listener({input: "foo"}, {}, function(){});
      expect(word).toBeDefined();
      expect(word).toEqual("foo");
*/
    });
  });

});
```

The second spec, where I call `haveBeenCalledWith`, says that `addListener` was not called at all. The third spec reports that `mostRecentCall.args` is undefined and it cannot access property 0 of undefined. (Further debugging revealed that `mostRecentCall` returns an empty object.)

Here's background.js, for good measure:

```
var word;
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (msg.input) {
      word = msg.input;
      sendResponse({success: "Message received"});
    }
});
```

If anybody can see what my mistake is, I'd appreciate it. I'm new to both Jasmine and requireJS, and I've run out of ideas to try.

Comment: You could try changing the order of the tests. If the first test is always succeeding and the others fail, it must be requirejs loading `background.js` only the first time and then using the already loaded instance.

Comment: That's interesting. You're right - the first test always passes, while the others fail. Do you know of any simple work-arounds for this problem?

Comment: I am not really familiar with RequireJS, so I can't propose a proper solution. But, taking RequireJS out of the equation might help :)

Answer (score 0):

I am using Jasmine 2.0.0 and only thing I did was the add the `var`  to chrome object:

```
var chrome ;
    beforeEach(function(){
         chrome = {
            runtime : {
                onMessage : {
                    addListener : function() {}
                }
            }
        }
        spyOn(chrome.runtime.onMessage, 'addListener').andCallThrough();
    });
```

Comment: I just double checked and I couldn't find a reason for it not to work.